# Accessing RabbitMQ logs in real time

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

I came across an interesting subject when reading the book "RabbitMQ in Action" by Manning. Apparently it's possible to set up consumers to be able to receive all RabbitMQ logging in real time in the consumer.

I read that RabbitMQ publishes logging to an exchange of type `topic` called `amq.rabbitmq.log`. Consumers can listen to specific severity levels, for example it can be filtered by setting the routing key to `error`, `warning` or `info`.

My question is; I installed a default RabbitMQ server on my PC, but I couldn't find any exchange called `amq.rabbitmq.log`. Only one which could be related is `amq.rabbitmq.trace`, but this one is used for events (events like queue.deleted, queue.created, ...), in other words that one is not what I'm looking for.

Can anyone bring clarification to my questions? Why is the `amq.rabbitmq.log` exchange not available on a clean RabbitMQ server installation?

citation:

> Perhaps when you were listing exchanges using rabbitmqctl you spotted
>   an exchange called amq.rabbitmq.log whose type is topic. RabbitMQ will
>   publish its logs to that exchange using the severity level as a
>   routing key - you'll get error, warning and info. Based on what you
>   learned from the previous chapters you can create a consumer to
>   listen to those logs and react accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

You have to enable it. Create the `/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf` file and ensure that this line is present in it:

```
log.exchange = true
```

I just grepped the [source](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-website) for the `rabbitmq.com` website and don't see that setting documented anywhere. If you'd like, file a new issue in that repository and I'll fix it, or open your own PR to do so.

Comment: What is the difference between the event exchange plugin and the above-mentioned configuration?

Comment: @Luke, configuration is done, but the exchange is still not created. I can't create it manually either, I get `access refused` when I try to create an exchange named `amq.rabbitmq.log`. Anything I'm forgetting?

Comment: Update: I found more information here: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/issues/1973. I think I need to update to the latest RabbitMQ version. I'm on 3.7.14 right now.

Comment: @Ozkan I think you didn't understand my question. RabbitMQ provides a plugin called the `evet_exchange` plugin which can be used to consume RabbitMQ events related to queues, exchanges, connections, users and many more. What is the difference between the logs consumer and the events consumer? As far as I know, these logs are same as the events that are generated.

Comment: @bumblebee You still didn't read my question completely right :), `amq.rabbitmq.log` is for pure logging. `event_exchange` is as you said. Look for amq.rabbitmq.trace in my question

Comment: @Ozkan - yes you'll need a more recent version. Sorry for the confusion. I forgot that we had to fix that "recently".

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit late, but hope it help someone. So far it works for me. The exchange "amq.rabbitmq.log" will be created automatically by the rabbitmq broker itself. The RabbitMQ broker version that I am using is: 3.8.1

add

> log.exchange = true

into your **rabbitmq.conf** file and restart your rabbitmq service.

You will need to restart your rabbitmq service everytime you had updated the rabbitmq.conf file.

open cmd and enter the following in windows:

1. rabbitmq-service stop
2. rabbitmq-service install
3. rabbitmq-service start
4. rabbitmqctl start_app